# Assigning multiple expressions for Symbolic variable in theano

Tags: python-3.x, theano

```
a = T.iscalar()
b = T.iscalar()
c = a
d = c+b
f = theano.function(
    inputs=[a,b],
    outputs=d
)
print(f(2,3))
```

This piece of code is executing properly and is printing 5. But if I change the code as below,

```
a = T.iscalar()
b = T.iscalar()
e = T.iscalar()
c = a
d = c+b
c = e
f = theano.function(
    inputs=[e,b],
    outputs=d
)
print(f(2,3))
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
theano.compile.function_module.UnusedInputError: theano.function was asked to create a function computing outputs given certain inputs, but the provided input variable at index 0 is not part of the computational graph needed to compute the outputs:
```

It seems that `c` is depending only on `a` and not on `e`.
My question is, Does theano allows only one expression for the assignment of a symbolic variable?